# Не переведена кнопка Edit question

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, правки

Не переведена кнопка `Edit question` ([пример вопроса](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1141968/178988)):

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил:

1. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14580

   > Редактировать вопрос
2. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14765

   > Редактировать вопросы и ответы